# how to set a series into a slice of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have temperature time series data in 15 minute intervals. 
If temp value is missing, i want to take mean of temp values of last/next 10 days at same time and put it in place of nan.

This is my code
This returns a pandas series with the values i want to keep for na values.

```
pd.Series(df.index[(df.Temp.isna())]).apply(last10daysmean)
```

How do i put the above. into this one below?

```
df.Temp[df.Temp.isna()]
```

This returns the na slots.

Comment: please paste  some sample data and expected result

Comment: Hi @Rex , is this solution works for your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the function `last10daysmean` from your question so I can substitute it with this:

```
def last10daysmean(x):
  return "TenDaysMeanPlaceholder"
```

You should try to have sample data when you post a question but I can just make temp data now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Temp": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan]
})
```

This fills the `isna` rows with the output of our dummy version for your `last10daysmean` function:

```
df.Temp[df.Temp.isna()] = df.Temp[df.Temp.isna()].apply(last10daysmean)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try of writing the row value by value apply function

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['value'] = np.random.random(len(pd.date_range(start='2019-1-1',end='2019-1-2',freq='15Min')))*10
df.index = pd.date_range(start='2019-1-1',end='2019-1-2',freq='15Min')
df.loc[df['value']<2,'value'

] = np.nan
```

Sample Dataframe

```
                        value
2019-01-01 00:00:00     NaN
2019-01-01 00:15:00     6.100087
2019-01-01 00:30:00     7.953615
2019-01-01 00:45:00     7.214069
2019-01-01 01:00:00     3.697723
2019-01-01 01:15:00     5.772333
2019-01-01 01:30:00     NaN
2019-01-01 01:45:00     2.827144
```

Function to get slice of dataframe

```
def last10daysmean(x,ind):
    df.loc[ind,'value'] = x.mean()
temp = df.index.map(lambda x: last10daysmean(df['value'].loc[x:x+10],x) if math.isnan(df.loc[x,'value']) else df.loc[x,'value'])
```

Out:

```
                        value
2019-01-01 00:00:00     5.901569
2019-01-01 00:15:00     6.100087
2019-01-01 00:30:00     7.953615
2019-01-01 00:45:00     7.214069
2019-01-01 01:00:00     3.697723
2019-01-01 01:15:00     5.772333
2019-01-01 01:30:00     5.594577
2019-01-01 01:45:00     2.827144
2019-01-01 02:00:00     6.409086
```